# Securing API's with Multi Factor Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, restful-architecture, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I want to secure my API with `Multi-factor-Authentication` on top of `Auth Token/JWT`. I have been searching but couldn't find any package that can work with `drf`. I am thinking to write my own django app. Any comments on what should be the architecture ?

One solution that comes to my mind is to introduce the token base architecture.If a user is accessing the mfa secured api then the request instance should be saved alongside a token and a sms should be sent to his mobile (In case of mobile as mfa) and response should be a that token. Then another request should be made to a `mfa` endpoint with `token and mfa-code`. Once verified, We would take his previous request object and complete the request.